# Does daily Charity alone atone for our sins? - [Proverbs 10:2, 11:4, 16:6, 19:17, 21:3]

Tags: proverbs, atonement

**If Charity to the poor is maintained daily to show our love to God & our neighbor, would our 'sins' be forgiven without requiring another sacrifice for atonement?**

**[Proverbs 10:2](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16381/jewish/Chapter-10.htm)** - "Treasures of wickedness will not avail, but **charity will save from death**." (לֹא־י֖וֹעִילוּ אוֹצְר֣וֹת רֶ֑שַׁע וּ֜צְדָקָ֗ה תַּצִּ֥יל מִמָּֽוֶת) + **[Proverbs 11:4](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16382/jewish/Chapter-11.htm)** - "Riches will not avail on the day of wrath, but **charity will save from death**." (לֹא־יוֹעִ֣יל ה֖וֹן בְּי֣וֹם עֶבְרָ֑ה וּ֜צְדָקָ֗ה תַּצִּ֥יל מִמָּֽוֶת) + **[Proverbs 16:6](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16387/jewish/Chapter-16.htm)** - "**With loving-kindness and truth will iniquity be expiated**, and through fear of the Lord turn away from evil." + **[Proverbs 19:17](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16390/jewish/Chapter-19.htm)** - "He who is gracious to a poor man lends to YHVH, and He will repay him His Reward." (מַלְוֵ֣ה יְ֖הוָה ח֣וֹנֵֽן דָּ֑ל וּ֜גְמֻל֗וֹ יְשַׁלֶּם־לֽוֹ) + **[Proverbs 21:3](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16392/jewish/Chapter-21.htm)** - "**Performing Charity and justice is preferred by YHVH to a sacrifice**." (עֲשׂה צְדָקָ֣ה וּמִשְׁפָּ֑ט נִבְחָ֖ר לַיהוָ֣ה מִזָּֽבַח)

- Does daily Charity alone atone for our sins? - [Proverbs 10:2, 11:4, 16:6, 19:17, 21:3]

Comment: What does the OT have to do with the new covenant regarding salvation?

Comment: This question is about what God prefers from us.

Comment: The Q was about atonement - this comes not from the OT except the expectation of the one who was to come.

Answer (score 1):

NO. Nothing except the atonement provided in Jesus' sacrifice will atone for sin. This deals with previous and future sin.

> Salvation is found in no one else, for there is no other name under heaven given to mankind by which we must be saved. Acts 4:12

The OT looked forward to sin being removed in Christ by those privy to seeing the plan of God from afar.

> Abraham your father rejoiced in that he should see my day--and he saw it and rejoiced. John 8:56

The daily sacrifices of animals were to 'cleanse' the sinner, but this was only a temporary solution, pointing to the one true sacrifice of a perfect Lamb, the man Jesus.

> For the Law, since it has only a shadow ... can never, by the same sacrifices which they offer continually every year, make those who approach perfect. 2 Otherwise, would they not have ceased to be offered, because the worshipers, having once been cleansed, would no longer have had consciousness of sins? 3 But in those sacrifices there is a reminder of sins every year. 4 **For it is impossible for the blood of bulls and goats to take away sins.** Heb 10:1-

> **All the prophets testify about him** that everyone who believes in him (Jesus) receives forgiveness of sins through his name. Acts 10:43

> ...because by the works of the Law none of mankind will be justified in His sight; for through the Law comes knowledge of sin. Rom 3:20

> But now apart from the Law the righteousness of God has been revealed, being witnessed by the Law and the Prophets, 22 but it is the righteousness of God through faith in Jesus Christ for all those who believe Rom 3:21-

Charity does not remove sin or the penalty of sin, but will aid in the giving of life as God intends we live by. Adam died a death of relationship with God and with men by choosing his own path. Through charity, we are choosing the way of God and not the way of men and will enjoy the better life God intends for all men *in this age.*

Comment: While I fully and totally agree with this answer, It could be greatly improved with some Bible references.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is not to exchange one kind of sin offering for another. Rather than continually sinning and making atonement, God desires that we understand his ways  and obey his will. In other words, faith to be genuine should first transform the heart and be reflected in all our external actions, i.e., in expressions of loving-kindness and charity.

- For I desire loving-kindness, and not sacrifices, and knowledge of God more than burnt offerings. —Hosea 6:6
- Of what use are your many sacrifices to Me? says the Lord. I am sated with the burnt-offerings of rams and the fat of fattened cattle; and the blood of bulls and sheep and he-goats I do not want… 16 Wash, cleanse yourselves, remove the evil of your deeds from before My eyes, cease to do evil. 17 Learn to do good, seek justice, strengthen the robbed, perform justice for the orphan, plead the case of the widow.
  —Isaiah 1:11-17